# setting up a local npm cache using artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I am using artifactory to set up a local npm registry cache.

I did

```
npm config set registry https://example.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/
```

and have jenkins run

```
npm install
```

unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any difference between using artifactory and using the normal npm registry (npm install uses the same amount of time for both approaches)

am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference, of course, is not in the install time. Most of the install time is consumed by network, so even if one of the solutions (local registry or Artifactory) is faster than the other, the difference won't be noticeable.

Here's a short, but not complete list of benefits of Artifactory over the simple local registry:

1. Artifactory works for a very broad set of technologies, not only npm, allowing using single tool for all your development and operational binaries [(including Vagrant, Docker, and what's not)](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/features/).
2. Artifactory supports multiple repositories, allowing you to control access, visibility and build promotion pipelines on top of them. [That's the correct way to manage binaries.](https://www.jfrog.com/article/binary-repository-management-2/)
3. Artifactory is priced by server, not by user, allowing bringing more people in the organization to use it without additional cost.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: Also using npm registry can be necessary if you are behind some proxy and npm repository is restricted for access